# Android handling app links internal network

Tags: android, applinks

Is there any specific reason why the app linking is not working (status is always undefined) if the assetlinks.json located at internal network.

I mean I  wonder about how this app linking is working? Is verification of assetlinks.json file handling by Google or App verifies this file by fetching it from the host defined at Android manifest by itself?

Comment: You should provide more detail about your use case, as Digital Asset Links is for _public_ information so using assetslinks.json on a private network means that it isn't indexable/verifiable by Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `assetlinks.json` file is verified by each local device, but Android is strict about the criteria for what qualifies as a valid file. Specifically:

1. Any response from the server besides HTTP 200 is treated as an error.
2. The certificate chain that must be verified, with a trusted root.

(Source: https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/v1/create-statement#website_statement_file)

Since you're hosting the file on an internal network, it's quite likely one (I'd guess the second) of these criteria is not being met.

Comment: Certificate is not the issue in my case but I beleive the issue is about http header. it is returning 304 Not Modified instead of 200.

Comment: the other thing worth to mentions is time out. If the verifier cannot create a connection to your web server and receive an HTTP response within five seconds, verification will fail. https://chris.orr.me.uk/android-app-linking-how-it-works/

Comment: "The assetlinks.json file is verified by each local device" do you have a source for this? It's not in the link you provided.